# Introductory Sentence/introductory clause

Tags: british-english, spoken-english

> Introductory clauses are dependent clauses that are often found at the
>   beginning of the sentence (**although they can be moved to the end of
>   the sentence, too, without confusing the meaning of the sentence**).

[Source](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/commas-after-introductory-clauses/)

Any examples of an introductory clause moved to the end of a sentence ?

Also, what is the difference between  an introductory sentence to open a paragraph on an essay, and  an introductory clause in terms of tone/suitability/effect? Is one better suited to a certain essay/article  over another ?

Comment: After removing some syntactically irrelevant elements, your own first sentence could be recast as ***Although they can be moved to the end of the sentence**, introductory clauses are dependent clauses that are often found at the beginning of the sentence.* Personally, although I think that *exact* example is stylistically somewhat clumsy, I've no problem with calling the highlighted element a "dependent clause" ***or*** an "introductory clause". But I really can't see why anyone would still want to call it an "introductory clause" if it were moved to the end rather than the start.

Answer (score 1):

A typical use of an introductory clause is in a conditional sentence.

> *If you work hard*, you will pass your exam.

You can place the clause at the end (it's not an introductory clause in that case because it is at the end.)

> You will pass your exam *if you work hard.*

Introductory clauses and the introductory sentences are not really comparable. An introductory sentence may have several clauses. An introductory sentence is not a grammatical construction, it is a rhetorical construction.